# Setting up analytics goal with regular expression for dynamic url with #

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I've been having difficulty setting up a goal for a dynamic URL:

```
paywall/payment/?guid=0cc30936a539429d9c4ec73417438717#/PaymentConfirmation
```

I've been advised that in order to capture `PaymentConfirmation` a regular expression is the way to go.

So far I haven't had any success and all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`[^/]*$` will match everything but slashes (`/`) zero or more times at the end of the string. If input is:

```
paywall/payment/?guid=0cc30936a539429d9c4ec73417438717#/PaymentConfirmation
```

Then the match will be:

```
PaymentConfirmation
```

`[...]` is a capturing group. `^` at the beginning of a capturing group will negate the match, (capture everything but ...). `/` is just a literal slash. `*` will repeat the previous zero or more times. And `$` means end of line.